# Prevent ATTACH DATABASE with SQLite Java

Tags: java, sqlite

Hey I'm currently trying to create a minecraft mod in which individual blocks have access to individual databases.
I thought I'd use SQLite.

However I absolutely need to stop ATTACH from working.
I thought about verifying every SQL string but I don't exactly know how to do it properly and it also seems a bit ugly.

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: There's a way to do it in C, but I doubt any of the coming Java interfaces to sqlite provide that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution! Just modify an existing Java SQLite Connector.

Here is the link to the pull request I made: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/pull/527#issue-462402792.

It works now, and I'm happy with it.